# Building CMake from Source on Mac M1

Tags: cmake, clang, clang++

I'm trying to build CMake on Mac M1

```
$ arch
arm64
```

`clang` version is

```
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.201)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

`clang++` version is

```
$ clang++ --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.201)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

CMake source is: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake.git, branch: master

To bootstrap, I run the command:

```
$ export CC=clang
$ export CXX=clang++
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/cmake/3.25.1
```

This results in the error:

```
---------------------------------------------
CMake 3.25.1, Copyright 2000-2022 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Cannot find appropriate C compiler on this system.
Please specify one using environment variable CC.
See cmake_bootstrap.log for compilers attempted.

---------------------------------------------
Log of errors: cmake-3.25.1/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log
---------------------------------------------
```

The error stated in the log is:

```
ld: unknown option: --rpath=/path/to/opt/anacounda3/lib:-L/path/to/opt/anaconda3/lib:
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Test failed to compile
```

I tried:

```
clang  -Wl,-rpath,/path/to/opt/anacounda3/lib:-L/path/to/opt/anaconda3/lib: -framework CoreFoundation
```

And this yields the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My `PATH` contains:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin:/usr/bin:
```

What could I do differently to resolve this?

Comment: What are the contents of `cmake-3.25.1/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log`?

Comment: What happens when running `./bootstrap`?

Comment: `./bootstrap` gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

My bash sourced the environment variables `LDFLAGS=/path/to/opt/anacounda3/lib:-L/path/to/opt/anaconda3/lib:`. Commenting this out fixed the problem.